# Как обратиться к значению req.files.location объекта upload.any()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

Помогите вывести в контроллере путь req.files.location объекта upload.any()

routes/app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const upload = require('../middleware/upload')
const controller = require('../controllers/app')
const router =  express.Router()

router.post('/', upload.any(), controller.app)

module.exports = router
```

middleware/upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer')
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
const errorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')
const keys = require('../config/keys')

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: keys.ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: keys.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: keys.REGION
})

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'verstesting',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: async function (req, file, cb) {
      const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      const path = "files.devices/" + req.body.id + "/" + today + "/" + file.originalname + ".jpg";
      cb(null, path);
      console.log('UPLOAD')
    }
  })
})
module.exports = upload
```

/controller/app.js

```
module.exports.app = function(req, res){
 console.log(req.files.location)  // тут то и не возвращает
}
```

Что весьма забавно, если вызывать upload.single('image'), то конструкция req.file.location успешно выводит путь, куда сохранилась картинка. Как я понял, что к upload.any() необходимо как-то иначе обращаться и req.files.location не работает.

Comment: Точно `location`? В документации на multer никакого `location` в свойствах `file` не упоминается, вместо этого есть `destination`. Но это детали. Суть в том, что `req.files` - это массив файлов, и необходимое Вам свойство надо искать в индивидуальных элементах этого массива (хотя бы потому, что может использоваться специфический storage engine, который будет нетривиальным образом распределять загружаемые файлы по подкаталогам, например).

Comment: в multer'e его нет. location упоминается в multer-s3. Он возвращает url к загруженному в bucket файлу.

Comment: А, ну тем более. multer-s3 - это как раз storage engine, и свойство присваивается каждому индивидуальному файлу.